# return specific value between two points

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a number of large data files and want to select certain results from the whole file. The file gives data for different parameters i.e.:

```
Number value 123
Option1 value parameter parameter
Option2 value parameter parameter
Option3 value parameter parameter
Number value 456
Option1 value2 parameter2 parameter2
Option2 value2 parameter2 parameter2
Option3 value2 parameter2 parameter2
Number value 789
Option1 value3 parameter3 parameter3
Option2 value3 parameter3 parameter3
Option3 value3 parameter3 parameter3
```

If, for example, I want to record the Option2 line but only the one that exists between Number value 123 and Number value 456 (the **bold** one) how can I do this? I have tried grep but I think it might require awk or some variation of this?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried? You've tagged your question with some tools that might be used to achieve your task, but you haven't included your attempt. Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. If you're asking for a recommendation as to what tool to use, then your question is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
awk '/Number value 123/,/Number value 456/{if ($0 ~ /Option2/){print}}' file
```

To print also the line below (asked in comments):

```
awk '/Number value 123/,/Number value 456/{if ($0 ~ /Option2/){print;getline;print}}' file
```

**Explanation**

`/Number value 123/,/Number value 456/` : Will get the range of lines between two patterns both of them included.

*Example*

```
$ awk '/Number value 123/,/Number value 456/' file
Number value 123
Option1 value parameter parameter
Option2 value parameter parameter
Option3 value parameter parameter
Number value 456
```

`if ($0 ~ /Option2/){print;getline;print}` : If our pattern maths the record `$0 ~ /Option2/` it will be *printed*, then `getline` will grab the **next record** (`$0`) that will be throw to the output by the next `print`.

*Example*

```
$ awk '/Number value 123/,/Number value 456/{if ($0 ~ /Option2/){print;getline;print}}' file
Option2 value parameter parameter
Option3 value parameter parameter
```

Comment: Is there a way to print two separate lines of text after one keyword? Option2 has one set of vales printed immediately after the text 'option2' and additional values printed on the line below in the output file. These are not re-labelled 'option2' but I need to collect both lines of data. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I have increased the amount of data my code is calculating and I now need to get 50 lines of data that are printed on separate lines after the word 'option1', before the data for option2 is printed. I was wondering if it is possible to recall that much data using the command you told me about?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sed` and `grep`  :

```
sed -n '/Number value 123/,/Number value 456/p' <fileName> | grep 'Option2'
```

`sed -n '/x/,/y/p'` prints the section of file between `x` and `y`, and then you can use the `grep` to search it.

Answer (score 1):

sed doesn't need the grep:

```
sed -n '/Number value 123/,/Number value 456/{/Option2/p}' file
```

Alternate awk if you know the data is in a set order:

```
awk '/Number value (123|456)/{a=!a}a && /Option2/' file
```